# URL mapping in Grails

Tags: grails, url-mapping

Suppose this is my URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/question1.xml

Currently in my UrlMappings.groovy I have  `

**"/$Question/$ask/$question1"(controller:"somecontroller")**` to handle the request.

If my URL changes to:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/askAgain/question1.xml

my URL mapping cannot handle it.

Is there a way I can get `ask/askAgain` to be referenced by `$ask` in my urlmapping.groovy?

Comment: have a look at the [docs on URL mappings](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/single.html#urlmappings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did to get around this.
I changed my URLMapping to

```
"/$Question/$ask**"(controller:"somecontroller")
```

If my URL is :

```
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/askAgain/question1.xml`
```

---

So now, `$ask** = ask/askAgain/question1.xml`

Then, If I want to remove question1.xml from that URL. I can use Regex to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide 2 mappings:

```
"/$Question/$ask/$question1"(controller: "somecontroller")
"/$Question/$ask/$askAgain/$question1"(controller: "somecontroller")
```

Comment: Thanks but there isnt a fix folder lvl. I mean the URL can be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/askAgain/askAgain1/question1.xml . Then I will need another URL Mapping. But thanks for your help. I found an alternative. I am now using wildcard ** to select all and using regex I can get what I wanted.  Thanks again

Comment: @RSM Great. You should post your approach as an answer or an update to your question.